# Moving data from a database to Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, dask, fastparquet, intake

I'm able to use [dask.dataframe.read_sql_table](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_sql_table) to read the data e.g. `df = dd.read_sql_table(table='TABLE', uri=uri, index_col='field', npartitions=N)`

What would be the next (best) steps to saving it as a parquet file in Azure blob storage?

From my small research there are a couple of options:

- Save locally and use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json (not great for big data)
- I believe [adlfs](https://github.com/dask/adlfs) is to read from blob
- use [dask.dataframe.to_parquet](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.to_parquet) and work out how to point to the blob container
- [intake](https://intake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) project (not sure where to start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ pip install adlfs`

```
dd.to_parquet(
    df=df, 
    path='absf://{BLOB}/{FILE_NAME}.parquet', 
    storage_options={'account_name': 'ACCOUNT_NAME',
                     'account_key': 'ACCOUNT_KEY'},
    )
```

Comment: Did this work? If yes, please accept your own answer.